# Is it possible to create a perpendicular lineString to another lineString when creating a point with onclick action?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to create a point B on the nearest lineString when I create another point A on the map. A and B are connected with a lineString which is perpendicular with the nearest lineString. I tried something but it's not working.. I search on Google for two hours but I didn't find a solution of my problem.. Someone can help me ?

For instance, it can be like this :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpt6F.jpg)

Thanks,
Vico

Comment: You should post your code in a minimal, reproducable example and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: But I don't have some code to show because it's confidential ^^' I create this post to know if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the Turf library's [nearestPointOnLine](http://turfjs.org/docs/#nearestPointOnLine) function. So if L is the LineString feature, and A is the newly created point, then you will have something like:

```js
    const B = turf.nearestPointOnLine(L, A)
    const tangent = {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [A.geometry.coordinates, B.geometry.coordinates]
    }
    map.addSource({ type: 'geojson', id: 'tangent', tangent})
```